# Check React useState() with console.log doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data from 2 text boxes using react useState. But when I check the `console.log`, it takes text letters one by one as an array.

create.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Form, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Create() {
    const[firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const[lastName, setLasttName] = useState('');

    console.log(firstName);
    console.log(lastName);
  return (
      <div>
    <div>create</div>
    <div>

    <Form>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
        <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" name='fName'  
        onChange={(e)=> setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
        placeholder="Enter first name" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" name='lName'  
        onChange={(e)=> setLasttName(e.target.value)} 
        placeholder="Enter last name" />
        </Form.Group>

        
        
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
        </Button>
</Form>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
    
import Create from './Components/create';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <Create/>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is how the console looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSWTv.png)

Console should be as shown below

[image: How the output should be]

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` function gets triggered every time the input changes. If you want it to trigger only once, when you are done typing, you can use `onBlur` this will assign the values only when the input field gets blurred.

Here's a sandbox for you to play with. Make sure you check the console to see when firstName gets updated https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-tharp-rfnxqg?file=/src/App.js

I would highly suggest that you check out [React Hook Forms](https://react-hook-form.com/)

Comment: I'm tying to implement a crud operation. Will this noBlur work for that? I'm trying to get user inputs and send to database

Comment: there is nothing wrong with what you are seeing in the `console.log(firstName)`, as @david Harvey answered you. the `onChange` function catches anything you type on your keyboard and for that the console.log will show you the changes. your `firstName` string value is basically the last result of your log as show in your picture is `thara` and nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I'm following a youtube tutorial actually. There the instructor gets the name at once instead of triggering for anything he types. I will attach a screenshot in my question how the instructor gets the output. I want to receive that type of output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Form, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Create() {
    const[firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const[lastName, setLasttName] = useState('');

    const submitForm =(e)=>{
     console.log(firstName)
console.log(lastName)
e.preventDefault()
}
  return (
      <div>
    <div>create</div>
    <div>

    <Form onSubmit={(e)=>submitForm(e)}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
        <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" name='fName'  
        onChange={(e)=> setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
        placeholder="Enter first name" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" name='lName'  
        onChange={(e)=> setLasttName(e.target.value)} 
        placeholder="Enter last name" />
        </Form.Group>

        
        
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
        </Button>
</Form>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Click button and look console